# Transformation of normal filter statement to hybrid filter statement using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Check the normal filter statement in input **Metadata/property[@token='filter1']/value** and **Metadata/property[@token='filter2']/value** must starts with logical expression,

**First step** If product contains any locations (*TOKYO/AGEO/FACTORY_A/FACTORY_B* etc...) then we should take the next step of converting the expression to hybrid filter statement mentioned in expected output.

Basically, if product contains any **location** as mentioned above the product will change to location mentioned in expected output.

**Second step** logical expression will also change in hybrid filter statement as its starts with **AND** operator at top level and inside **OR** operation is bifurcated, Please have a look at the hybrid statement closely in expected output. Where as normal filter statement starts with **OR** expression at the top level and inside bifurcated with **AND** expression mentioned in input.

I tried the first step with regex commands and I am new to regex commands, to validate the structure of the input filter statement, Need help with to convert the normal filter statement to hybrid filter statement mentioned in expected output.

**Input**

```
<Metadata id="WTPart_1398662" source="wt.part.WTPart|com.ptc.PHBase|com.ptc.PHModel">
         <Property token="filter1">
            <Value>
            (OR
            (AND (PRODUCT 'TOKYO') (DATE_RANGE '' '2022-03-31 00:00:00.0’))
            (AND (PRODUCT 'PH_U-HD2'))
            (AND (PRODUCT 'PH_U-HD’))
            (AND (PRODUCT 'AGEO') (DATE_RANGE '' '2022-01-31 00:00:00.0’))
             )
             </Value>
         </Property>
         <Property token="filter2">
            <Value>
            (OR
            (AND (PRODUCT 'FACTORY_A') (DATE_RANGE '' '2023-01-31 00:00:00.0'))
            (AND (PRODUCT 'FACTORY_B') (DATE_RANGE '' '2023-02-28 00:00:00.0'))
            (AND (PRODUCT 'PRODUCT_A'))
            (AND (PRODUCT 'PRODUCT_B'))
             )
             </Value>
         </Property>
 </Metadata>
```

**Expected output**

```
<Metadata id="WTPart_1398662" source="wt.part.WTPart|com.ptc.PHBase|com.ptc.PHModel">
         <Property token="filter1">
            <Value>
            (AND
            (OR (PRODUCT 'PH_U-HD')(PRODUCT 'PH_U-HD2’))
            (OR
            (AND (IS 'LOCATION' 'Ageo')(DATE_RANGE '' '2022-01-31 00:00:00.0’))
            (AND (IS 'LOCATION' 'Tokyo')(DATE_RANGE '' '2022-03-31 00:00:00.0’))
            ))
             </Value>
         </Property>
         <Property token="filter2">
            <Value>
            (AND
            (OR
            (PRODUCT 'PRODUCT_A')PRODUCT 'PRODUCT_B'))
            (OR
            (AND (IS 'LOCATION' 'FACTORY_A') (DATE_RANGE '' '2023-01-31 00:00:00.0'))
            (AND (IS 'LOCATION' 'FACTORY_B') (DATE_RANGE '' '2023-02-28 00:00:00.0'))
             ))
             </Value>
         </Property>
 </Metadata>
```

I tried the below XSL, which is the First step, I want to validate the structure of the input filter statement, If it is true which means input filter statement satisfy the **First step** then I want to proceed with **Second step** to convert the input filter statement (input) to hybrid filter statement mentioned in expected output. Need help on the same.

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet  
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:my="http://itcinfotec.com/my-namespace"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    

    <xsl:template match="Metadata[@source='wt.part.WTPart|com.ptc.PHBase|com.ptc.PHModel']/Property[@token='filter1']/Value | Metadata[@source='wt.part.WTPart|com.ptc.PHBase|com.ptc.PHModel']/Property[@token='filter2']/Value">
        <xsl:param name="APEX" />

        <xsl:variable name="isBalanced"
            select="count(tokenize($APEX, '\(')) = count(tokenize($APEX, '\)'))" />
        <xsl:variable name="isTopLevelOR"
            select="starts-with(normalize-space($APEX), '(OR') and substring-after(normalize-space($APEX), '(OR')" />

        <xsl:variable name="validSubStatements">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="$APEX"
                regex="\((AND)\s(\(PRODUCT '[^']*'\))(\s\(DATE_RANGE ('[^']*' '[^']*')\))?\)">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:sequence
                        select="regex-group(1) = 'AND' and starts-with(regex-group(2), '(PRODUCT ') and (not(regex-group(3)) or starts-with(regex-group(3), ' (DATE_RANGE '))" />
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:sequence select="false()" />
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:sequence
            select="$isBalanced and $isTopLevelOR and $validSubStatements" />
    </xsl:template>
    
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```